# why view pager class is not in android.app package , I don't want to use support library

Tags: android

why view pager class is not in android.app package  , if we want to use this we have to use support library , if my app's minimum api level  is 15 than why should i use support library ... I don't want to use support library

Comment: If you don't want use support library view pager use FragemntTransaction insted.

Comment: actually i want to give slide effect .......

Comment: Ask the Google Android developers or look at the source code. I don't know for definite but I suspect the `ViewPager` class might rely on other support library code.

Comment: Let me add a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FragmentTransaction instead of View Pager. and You can Custom Slide effect as follows.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
      .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right)
      .replace(R.id.mainactivity, your fragment, fragment Tag).commit();
```